# Why does Rust Analyser disagree with the compiler?

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I'm using the latest stable version: rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24).

Rust Analyser needs the import:

```
use chrono::offset::TimeZone;
```

in order to accept the expression:

```
Utc.ymd(1970, 1, 1).and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 200)
```

(It highlights the `.ymd` as `{unknown}`.)

If I add the import, the compiler issues a warning:

```
   Compiling foo v0.1.0 (/home/fadedbee/foo)
warning: unused import: `chrono::offset::TimeZone`
 --> src/bar.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use chrono::offset::TimeZone;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default
```

How can I make Rust Analyser (in vscode), and the compiler, both happy?

---

Update:

As rodrigo correctly deduced, the only uses of `.ymd` are within a  `#[cfg(test)]` section.

Comment: You can try add `#[allow(unused_imports)]` before `use` statement

Comment: Running it locally without the import results in `ymd method not found in \`chrono::Utc\`` on `rustc 1.46.0` using `chrono 0.4`. What version of chrono are you using?

Comment: Running it on the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c8c6d2cf4a4e7927966fdf88670227d) results in the same error message with the help `the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it: use chrono::TimeZone;`, adding it solves the issue

Comment: Maybe your use of `Utc.ymd(...)` is conditionally compiled, as in a `#[cfg(test)]`?

Comment: With the information provided, the problem cannot be reproduced. The code in the question compiles without warnings once the import is added. Could you provide a minimal example reproducing the problem?

Comment: @rodrigo Many thanks, that was an impressive leap.  The only uses of `.ymd` were in a `#[cfg(test)]` section.  Moving the `use` inside of that section solved the problem.